# Change The Values of the Percentages, Not The Loading Bars

Tags: javascript

What I'm trying to do is get the text to end at 98% and 160% but they are stopping at 60% and 100% which is where I want the bars to stop, but not the text. Here is what I have:

```
window.addEventListener("resize", sreen_height);
        sreen_height();
        function sreen_height(){
            var height = window.innerHeight;
            document.getElementById("wrap").style.height=(height) +'px';
        }
        var i=0;
        var it=0;
        var j=0;
        var jt=0;



        function increase_bar_current() {
            document.getElementById("current-speed").style.width=i+'%';
            document.getElementById("current-value").textContent=it;
             i++;
             it++;
            t_c = setTimeout(function(){increase_bar_current()}, 20);
            if(i==61){
                clearTimeout(t_c);
                increase_bar();
            }
            if(it==98){
                clearTimeout(t_c);
            }
        }



        function increase_bar() {
            document.getElementById("increase").style.width=j+'%';
            document.getElementById("value").textContent=jt;
             j++;
             jt++;
            t = setTimeout(function(){increase_bar()}, 20);
            if(j==101){
                clearTimeout(t);
            }
            if(jt==161){
                clearTimeout(t);
            }
        }

        setTimeout(increase_bar_current, 1500);
```

`i` is the first bar I want to load to 60%, `it` I want to say 98% when its finished loading,
`j` is the second bar I want to load to 100%, `jt` I want to say 160% when its finished loading.

What am I doing wrong?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5FY2K/
For some reason it's not showing the progression while loading the text (0% to 98% and 0% to 160%) or the bar from 0% to 60% and 0% to 100%.. can someone help with this? maybe its the fiddle?

Comment: can you give us a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) to work with? Its hard to work with just a wall of code without comments - this also has CSS interactions which are hard to grok without a testbed :P

Comment: @IvyLynx sure ill set that up now

Comment: @IvyLynx updated with fiddle

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what _is_ happening versus what you _want_ happening. Is it that the bars aren't filling up as much as you want them or more? The whole "160%" thing on a progress bar is confusing, why do you want it there, what is it supposed to represent?

Comment: Ok the reason your fiddle doesn't work is because you included that event listener on top. the element it references doesn't exist. You should really check the devtools console for errors when things don't work. here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2MJxq/4/ - does this do what you want? (cause it's still unclear to me what exactly you need it to do). In the fiddle, I've made the timeouts slower so that it's easier to see what's happening.

Comment: @IvyLynx it loads the bars the way i want it to, but I want the percentages to stop at 98% for bar 1 and 160% for bar 2.. thats the part i couldnt figure out

Comment: like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/2MJxq/5/)? What exactly is the point of all this? See the parts I commented out. Those conditions will _never_ be met because the way you've arranged your `if` statements and increments, the timeout will be stopped before the counters ever go that far. It also seems like your `it` and `jt` variables are completely useless. You should state your questions more clearly so that it's easy to understand what you expect to happen and why everything in the code is the way it is.

Comment: @IvyLynx I'm trying to load Bar1's text to 98%, while the actual bar loads to 60% like it was before.. and Bar2s text to 160%, while the bar loads to 100%.. pretty much I want the text from this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2MJxq/5/ and i want the loading bars to stop where they do on this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2MJxq/4/

Comment: If you want arbitrary preset ratios like that _put them in your code!_. Since you want such a specific relationship between the numbers, why not hardcode it? http://jsfiddle.net/2MJxq/6/